# How to access a localhost server from one computer to another on the same network

Tags: java, spring, networking

I have a spring boot application (Spring Web) which has a tomcat server embedded into it (maven dependency). The application is a server and consists of several HTTP routes. This application is on my laptop. I would like to execute the application on my laptop, and be able to RESTful calls (e.g. GET, POST etc) to the server. How can I make requests to the server from my computer?

I've checked out several tutorials and they tend to use XAMP or another similar application so not sure on how to go about this. Thank you.

Comment: Use any http client to call your server? i.e. `curl`

Comment: The same way you access it from the same computer, just replace `localhost` with the ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your war is deployed on your server, you can send any REST call to it using curl, a browser, or my personal favorite for testing is Postman as it circumvents cross-domain issues.

To make the REST call simply use the IP address of the server instead of localhost. You can get the IP address of the machine using ifconfig or whatsmyip.org

```
http://<IP address>/...
```

Comment: when you type `ipconfig` it should be `IPv4 Address`